# Change string according to csv file

Tags: python, csv, replace

I have to open several websites to check something. The only difference between the links to every page is an id which I have stored in a CSV file. 
I want to iterate through the CSV file and replace the id for every website.

I want to do it with the replace statement and change the xxx in the link. But it does´nt change the id and tries to open the link with the xxx several times.

```
import webbrowser
import csv

link = "https://website.com/de/tour/xxx/geometrie.html"
with open('spielbergList.csv', 'rb') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     for row in reader:
         print(row)
         link.replace("xxx", str(row))
         webbrowser.open(link)
         print(link)
         link = "https://website.com/de/tour/xxx/geometrie.html"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the replace method of a string returns a new string and doesn't modify the old one in place so you have to catch the new string in another variable or re-use your link variable

```
link = link.replace("xxx", str(row))
```

The reason for this, is that strings are immutable (you can't modify them after creation)

```
>>> a = 'hello world'
>>> a.replace('hello', 'hi')
'hi world'
>>> a # a is still hello world
'hello world'
>>> a = a.replace('hello', 'hi')
>>> a
'hi world'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace` returns a new string, so you will have to catch it:

`link = link.replace("xxx", str(row))`

Although it will be better to use a "template" url instead of reassigning `link` to the url with the `xxx` in every iteration. 
An example of having a template url and using `format` to create the required url:

```
import webbrowser
import csv

basic_url = "https://website.com/de/tour/{}/geometrie.html"
with open('spielbergList.csv', 'rb') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     for row in reader:
         print(row)
         webbrowser.open(basic_url.format(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `format`.

```
for row in reader:
    webbrowser.open('https://website.com/de/tour/{0}/geometrie.html'.format(row))
```